# difference between document.all and document.forms[0]

Tags: javascript

Can any one explain what is the difference between

```
document.all
```

and the 
`document.forms[0]` please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.all` gives you a reference to an array-like object containing all elements of the document *in Internet Explorer* (IE). `Document.forms[0]` gives you a pointer to the first form element in the document, *in all browsers*

The 2 are quite different then. If your form had a name attribute, say 'myform', then in IE that form could be referenced with `document.all.myform`

`document.all` is deprecated from IE version 5 and up. You can still use it though, even in IE9 it's still available. Often it's used to test if the browser is IE:

```
if (document.all) {
  //o no, it's IE again! We have to do it another way!
}
```

Referencing forms in the form of `document.forms[0]` is considered bad practice. More on that can be found [here](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#forms)

**NOTE: Since this answer was first written IE11 has been introduced which dropped support for document.all [See Compatibility changes in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information**

Comment: @Kooilnc so the two methods are only useful in IE? suppose the same code if we want to run in Chrome or safari what to do?

Comment: @Mihir: bottom line = you can use `document.all` in Internet Explorer and you'll only explicitly need it in Internet Explorer < 5. So `document.forms` is available for all browsers, including IE.

Comment: "o no, it's IE again! We have to do it another way!" too bad this test is passed by your beloved Chrome too.

Comment: @Annie: sure, and the same goes for Opera. What makes you think Chrome is my 'beloved' browser then?

Answer (score 3):

The document.all property is an array of all the HTML elements that are in the document. while Document.forms[0] is the first form in the document. You should avoid using document.all.

> Internet Explorer 4 introduced the
>   document.all DOM (document object
>   model) to allow access to the various
>   parts of the web page. Soon after that
>   the standard DOM method getElementById
>   was introduced and is therefore
>   available in all version 5+ browsers.
>   This means that the document.all
>   references are **only** needed to
>   support IE4.Just about no one runs IE4
>   any more and so support for the
>   document.all DOM is no longer
>   required.

To learn more on how to use document.form[0] read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html).

Answer (score 0):

at first you have use document.all.myform to access your form .
in the second format you can use document.forms[0] to access your form

```
     both one two is same in function but two is better than one
                             document.all.myform using this your searching all the way rome.
```