# JavaScript NaN error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with radio buttons:

```html
<ul class='likert'>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value=5 required>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value=4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value=3 checked="checked">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value=2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value=1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In Firefox and Chrome,

```js
parseInt(document.forms["question_form"]["q1"].value)
```

returns 3 (or whatever) but in Internet Explorer I get ‘NaN’.

Comment: which version of IE

Comment: also you probably shouldn't be using forms. take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5590787/5523033)

Comment: IE seems to return a HTMLCollection from `document.forms["question_form"]["q1"]`, since the names are not unique. The returned collection doesn't have `value` property.

Comment: @Teemu I just checked Object.prototype.toString.call(parseInt(document.forms["question_form"]["q1"].value)) and got [object Number] in both IE and Chrome

Comment: @user1234 `NaN` is a number. `typeof NaN === "number"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE returns a HTMLCollection when the names are not unique in `document.forms["question_form"]["q1"]`.

See Remarks at [IHTMLElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703928(v=vs.85).aspx)

> > "If duplicate names are found, a collection of those named items is returned."

You can get the checked value for example like this:

```
var val = document.querySelector('.likert input:checked').value);
```

Comment: What a blatant violation of [DOM form namedItem](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-nameditem). It should return a  [RadioNodeList](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#radionodelist) collection, which has a [value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dom-radionodelist-value).

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers, a pure js solution is:

```
document.querySelector('input:checked').value;
```

If you can use jQuery, it's a bit more easy and elegant:

```
$("input:checked").val();
```