# radio button value not accessible in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a radio button on my HTML page:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="calc_risk(); return false;" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"> No
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Inside my javascript function I can access the value via:

```
function calc_risk () {
    var a = document.forms["myForm"]["q1"].value;
}
```

In firefox that variable contains 1 or 0 as expected (depending on which radio button I've selected). In IE11 the value is undefined. Why is the radio button not working in IE11?

**EDIT**

I'm using jquery now to access the value:

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='q1']:checked").val();
```

Works in both browsers. Make sure that jquery is included in your header section by adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you make a snippet?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864049/1169519

Comment: so is microsoft just stupid and should I avoid IE support?

Comment: @user3182532 welcome to the club

Comment: I wouldn't take it like that, IE is just different = ). There's a more or less cross-browser solution in my answer, though.

Comment: which solution are you referring to teemu? do you mean jquery? is jquery working in every browser?

Comment: At the end of the linked answer there's a `querySelector` for catching the value, it is a standard DOM method.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to access a `value` property on an [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection) and get the value of the first checked radio button inside it is a relatively new feature in the web api specifications.

Internet Explorer (being an old browser that isn't getting any new development work beyond security patches) doesn't support it.

You can loop over the collection and test for the first checked element instead.

```
var a = get_first_checked_value(document.forms["myForm"]["q1"]);

function get_first_checked_value(form_controls) {
    for (var i = 0; i < form_controls.length; i++) {
        if (form_controls[i].checked) {
            return form_controls[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution and tested in IE 11 and Chrome browser.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="calc_risk(this); return false;" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"> No
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            function calc_risk (theForm) 
            {
                var q1Values = theForm.q1;
                for (i=0 ;i<q1Values.length;i++)
                {
                    if(q1Values[i].checked)
                    {
                        alert(q1Values[i].value);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```